# Rails - undefined method `user' for ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, model, render

I have the action called **dashboard** in the **Users** controller.
It's something like this:

```
   def dashboard
      @data = @user.datas.includes(:user).includes(:images)
      render 'datas/show'
   end
```

and I am getting error **undefined method 'user' for #ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc702d34868>**
 on this line:

```
= render 'users/header', :user => @data.user
```

How is that possible? In the `@data` variable is everything what's needed...

Comment: Your `@data` variable contains several records, use `= render 'users/header', :user => @data.first.user` instead or even, you already have it, the variable `@user` (also the `@variables` are shared between controller's action, view and associated partials, so you should not have to pass the variable `@user` or `@data` to this partial)

Comment: @MrYoshiji - I know some folks answer questions in comments, but it's usually in the case of almost trivial answers. I'm curious why you chose not to use the "answer" mechanism in this case.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin because I'm too lazy to "format" a nice answer. A comment does not need bold, indentation or examples. I try with first a comment and if the Asker wants further infos, I post an answer

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem** is that you are calling an instance method on a list of objects.

```
@data = @user.datas.includes(:user).includes(:images)
```

This is actually an array of Data objects belonging to the user's instance `@user`.

**To solve this**, you can get the first element of the list and get its user:

```
= render 'users/header', :user => @data.first.user
```

But you should know that **all the `@variables` are shared** between the controller's action, the view and the invoked partials. With this in mind, you will notice that you can simply do the following:

```
# in datas/show.html.haml
= render 'users/header'

# in users/_header.html.haml
# you can use the @user variable as your wishes
= @user
```